# Change label from Newrelic "MySQL (subquery) select" to custom label

Tags: laravel, eloquent, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have using Newrelic with Laravel application.

Whenever I use simple queries then newrelic shows table name with it.

But in case of sub-queries it shows **MySQL (subquery) select**
[image]

I am using Laravel Eloquent for queries.

Can you please help me how I can replace this label with custom table name like **MySQL subquery_customer_table select**

Thank You in advance!